# Shaded area on argand plane if $|\bar z + zi| \leq 2$

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

The shaded area on the argand plane if $|\bar z + zi| \leq 2$.
and find the maximum value for $Arg(z)$

**My attempt:**

Let $$z=x+iy$$
$$|(x-iy)+(x+iy)i| \leq 2$$

Then $$|(x-iy)+(xi-y)|\leq 2$$

so we get $$x-\sqrt2 \leq y \leq x+{\sqrt2}$$

Then how can I determine the maximum value for $Arg(z)$?

Is there a geometrical method instead of $z=x+iy$ ?

Comment: Show how you deduced $|(x-iy)+(xi-y)|\leq 2$.  Draw a picture of the region: then can you determine the max of arg?

Comment: From your inequality I get that it must be $\;x-\sqrt2<y<x+\sqrt2\;$ , so we have two limiting straight lines for the imaginary part...Check this and try to continue from here.

Comment: $|(x-iy)+(xi-y)|=|x-y||1+i|,$ whence DonAntonio's hint.

Comment: @DonAntonio yes. I corrected my answer. So I have two straight Lines and the region in between them. Any help  to find max Arg(z)?

Comment: @GEdgar It's now given.

Comment: @AngeloMark Well, if you already have a sketch of that domain, you can see you have a neighborhood of zero completely within it, and thus you can have elements there with *any* argument... But I'm not sure what do you understand by "argument": does it have to be an angle say in the usual standard interval \;$(-\pi, \pi]\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio principle argument is Arg(z). So Max is $\pi$

Comment: @AngeloMark Well, there you go...That's the maximal value, of course.